# How do I call a function in a user control in form1 from from2?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have form 1 with a user control having label I wish to Update when I click a button in form 2.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on constructor of form 2:

```
private firstForm;
public Form2(Form1 firstForm)
{
    this.firstForm = firstForm;
}
```

Then on button click on your `Form2` do this, just make sure the
function you are calling from `Form1` is public:

```
private Form1 firstForm;
public Form2(Form1 firstForm)
{
    this.firstForm = firstForm;
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstForm.Update();
}
```

So in `Form1` when calling `Form2` do this with the button click:

```
Form2 form2;
public void Update()
{
    //Update Something
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2 = new Form(this);
    form2.Show();
}
```